# Rspec (for Michael Hartl example) for the definition of relationship following users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, refactoring

I'm trying to make a spec test for the [MHartl's example](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users).
As it follows bellow my difficult is for #Follows a user.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower

  # Follows a user.
  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end
```

For my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  let(:user) { build(:user) }

  describe 'Validations' do
    it 'has a valid factory' do
      expect(user).to be_valid
    end

    it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:password) }
    it { should validate_confirmation_of(:password) }
  end


  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:other_user) { create(:user) }

  describe '#following?' do
    it "expect relationship between two users to be empty" do
      expect(user.active_relationships).to be_empty
    end
  end

  describe '#follow' do
    it "creates the active relationship between two users" do
      user.follow(other_user)
      expect(user.active_relationships.first.followed_id).to eq(other_user.id)
    end

    it "creates the passive relationship between two users" do
      user.follow(other_user)
      expect(other_user.passive_relationships.first.follower_id).to eq(user.id)
    end
  end

  describe '#unfollow' do
    it "destroys the active relationship between two users" do
      user.follow(other_user)
      user.unfollow(other_user)
      expect(user.active_relationships.find_by.followed_id).to change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
```

My failures :

```
1) User#unfollow destroys the active relationship between two users
     Failure/Error: active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

  2) User#follow creates the passive relationship between two users
     Failure/Error: expect(other_user.passive_relationships.first.follower_id).to eq(user.id)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `passive_relationships' for #<User:0x0000010c4146e8>
```

If you need more info about this post, please fell free to ask!
and please tell me were can I learn more about this specs tests.
thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `:passive_relationships` relationship in the `User` model that mirrors the `:active_relationships` relationship:

```
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                 foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                 dependent:   :destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

May be better to create this other user in `let`, and replace `build` with `create`, since you are not validation a new unsaved record:

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let(:other_user) { create(:user) }
```

then

```
user.follow(other_user)
```

Comment: Hi there I just updated with your help!  but I got the error: `You cannot call create unless the parent is saved`

Comment: the test works for `user.follow(other_user)` but didn't for `user.following?(other_user).should be_valid`

Comment: Hey @Малъ Скрылевъ , I have encountered other issues... could you please check out ? thanks

Comment: @Jony you have no passive_relationships, just add it with the same manner as active_relationships

Comment: @Jony that shows that no `active_relationships` with followed_id as other_user.id